# KeyDown Event not fired for TextBox in UWP

Tags: uwp, textbox, win-universal-app

When I press the Enter key, the `KeyDown` event for the `TextBox` is not fired if its `AcceptsReturn` property is set to true. How can I identify when the Enter key is pressed for a `TextBox` with `AcceptsReturn` set to `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the below code, and its works for me,

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
KeyEventHandler keyeventHandler = new KeyEventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);

textBox.AddHandler(TextBox.KeyDownEvent, keyeventHandler, true);

private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
*** now Enter Key gets fired eventhough when i set AcceptsReturn as True ***
}
```

Comment: Looks like `.AddHandler` works because of the [third parameter, `handledEventsToo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_AddHandler_) of which MSDN says "*Do not routinely ask to rehandle a routed event, because it interferes with the intended design of the Windows Runtime event system for control compositing.*" Other downside: It's too late to turn the `Enter` off. Setting `e.Handled = true;` here doesn't stop the Enter from happening in the TextBox. But otherwise a great answer; this works.

Comment: @ruffin how did you solve this problem? Did you just remove the last newline?

Comment: Thank you! It was working for me, just had to change the argument type from `KeyEventArgs` to `KeyRoutedEventArgs` for the second parameter of the `textBox_KeyDown` function, because the compiler didn't accept. Maybe you can correct your answer

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to completely disable the new line (like @ruffin wants to), subscribe to the PreviewKeyDown event via code behind and set `e.Handled` to `true`.

```
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var keyeventHandler = new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyDown);
        uiText.AddHandler(PreviewKeyDownEvent, keyeventHandler, handledEventsToo: true);
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> When i press enter key, Key Down event for the Text Box is not fired. This happens only when i set Accepts Return property of text Box as true.

This is because if `AcceptsReturn` is set to true, the `TextBox` allows newline characters, so when you press enter key, it will start a new line, and the KeyDown event won't be fired. Otherwiser, if it is set to false(by default it is false), when you press enter key, it makes this `TextBox` in the input focus state, the KeyDown event can get fired.

> How can i identify when the Enter key is pressed ?

I'm afraid you can not use KeyDown event to identify the Enter key in this scenario, but you can use [TextBox.TextChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox.TextChanged);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) in the code behind to get notified since it will start a new line when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Hi @Grace, Thanks for the answer, but i found a solution. I used Handler for this scenario, and now it gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

in XAML:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
```

in code behind:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);
    }
```

from the output, you can see that Enter is recognized.

Comment: Sorry, if i press enter key, KeyDown event not fired. TextBox Handles When enter key is pressed. If i didn't set Accepts Returns for TextBox as true, Key down event is fired when i press enter key. But if i set AcceptsReturn as true, then KeyDown event is not fired